# PostgreSQL runs out of memory in the middle of query

Tags: postgresql, memory

I am running a PostgreSQL 11 database in AWS RDS in a `db.t2.xlarge` instance (4 CPU 16 Gb RAM) with 4 Tb of storage. My query is based on a fairly large table (48 Gb -- 243.711.955 rows), but nothing that PostgreSQL should not be able to handle.

I'm running a simple query (I add the query plan in case that can give any insight), but after ~10 hours, the storage space drops dramatically to nil, and the query fails with:

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16401/321099.3525": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

I tried to solve the problem with additional storage (I added 1 Tb to the database and ran a `VACCUM` on all the tables -- I know that `autovaccum` is set on in RDS instances), but the problem persisted. I am afraid that adding space might not be the possible solution since the database is taking less than 1 Tb:

```
         name         |    owner    |   size
----------------------+-------------+-----------
 rdsadmin             | rdsadmin    | No Access
 <my_database>        | <user_db>   | 317 GB
```

I do not completely understand the way PostgreSQL creates temporary files, are those hashes or temporary `ORDER BY` indexes (?), but I have a significant amount of those in my db:

```
       datname        | Temporary files | Size of temporary files
----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------
 rdsadmin             |               0 |                       0
 template0            |               0 |                       0
 postgres             |               0 |                       0
 <my_database>        |            1079 |            991097557473
 template1            |               0 |                       0
```

Should I keep adding storage space until the query run (RDS has a "emergency storage" for these cases)? or there is some kind of configuration that I am missing before running my query?

EDIT: Add query.

Query:

```sql
    with times as (
        select name_source,
               id_source,
               run,
               init_dt,
               hour_along,
               ntile(3) over (partition by run, date_part('year', init_dt), id_source order by hour_along) as t,
               height,
               traj_dt,
               geom
        from hysplit_process.clean_trajectories
    ),
         dates_for_t as (
             select distinct on (
                id_source,
                name_source,
                run,
                date_part('year', init_dt),
                t) name_source,
                   id_source,
                   run,
                   t,
                   traj_dt
             from times
             order by id_source, name_source, run, date_part('year', init_dt), run, t, traj_dt desc
         ),
         agg_trajs_by_t as (
             select name_source,
                    id_source,
                    run,
                    t,
                    init_dt,
                    avg(st_x(geom)) as avg_lon,
                    avg(st_y(geom)) as avg_lat,
                    avg(height)     as avg_height
             from times
             group by name_source, id_source, run, init_dt, t
         )
    select t.name_source,
           t.id_source,
           t.run,
           t.t,
           t.init_dt,
           d.traj_dt,
           st_setsrid(st_makepoint(t.avg_lon, t.avg_lat), 4326) as geom,
           t.avg_height
    from agg_trajs_by_t as t
             left join dates_for_t as d
                       using (run, t);
```

Query plan:

```
                                                                              QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Right Join  (cost=274164346.44..274773926.31 rows=24371195 width=104)
   Merge Cond: ((d.run = t.run) AND (d.t = t.t))
   CTE times
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=90827593.60..97529672.28 rows=243711952 width=100)
           ->  Sort  (cost=90827593.60..91436873.48 rows=243711952 width=96)
                 Sort Key: clean_trajectories.run, (date_part('year'::text, clean_trajectories.init_dt)), clean_trajectories.id_source, clean_trajectories.hour_along
                 ->  Seq Scan on clean_trajectories  (cost=0.00..6897785.40 rows=243711952 width=96)
   CTE dates_for_t
     ->  Unique  (cost=72144047.24..73971886.88 rows=40000 width=56)
           ->  Sort  (cost=72144047.24..72753327.12 rows=243711952 width=56)
                 Sort Key: times.run, times.t, times.traj_dt DESC
                 ->  CTE Scan on times  (cost=0.00..4874239.04 rows=243711952 width=56)
   CTE agg_trajs_by_t
     ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=88804047.24..95932621.83 rows=24371195 width=80)
           Group Key: times_1.name_source, times_1.id_source, times_1.run, times_1.init_dt, times_1.t
           ->  Sort  (cost=88804047.24..89413327.12 rows=243711952 width=96)
                 Sort Key: times_1.name_source, times_1.id_source, times_1.run, times_1.init_dt, times_1.t
                 ->  CTE Scan on times times_1  (cost=0.00..4874239.04 rows=243711952 width=96)
   ->  Sort  (cost=3857.54..3957.54 rows=40000 width=16)
         Sort Key: d.run, d.t
         ->  CTE Scan on dates_for_t d  (cost=0.00..800.00 rows=40000 width=16)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=6726307.90..6848163.88 rows=24371195 width=80)
         ->  Sort  (cost=6726307.90..6787235.89 rows=24371195 width=80)
               Sort Key: t.run, t.t
               ->  CTE Scan on agg_trajs_by_t t  (cost=0.00..487423.90 rows=24371195 width=80)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL below version 11 materializes all CTEs. It looks like the required temporary storage is bringing you down (although I am surprised that the problem is in `base/16401/321099.3525`). Try writing the query without CTEs or try using PostgreSQL v12.

Comment: Your query plan doesn't show any Hash Joins, so it must not be hash files.  It must be temporary files for sort, or tuplestore files for the CTEs.  Try running each CTE separately and see if they finish and what they do to "Size of temporary files".

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your suggestions. @jjanes, I tried restarting the AWS instance, but the temporary files are still there, it is safe to get rid of those? Also, unfortunately AWS doesn't support PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: @topcat, it is probably not the temp files themselves that are still around, but just the statistics for them.  Just write down the numbers, and subtract them from future numbers to get the difference.  You could do `select pg_stat_reset()`, but that is a drastic action to take just to avoid doing some arithmetic.

Comment: Even without the CTEs there are multiple sorts that _will_ happen in this query, and you can't possibly sort a 48 GB table in 16 GB of memory.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio. I'm not able to check directly the RAM usage on RDS, but I don't see big changes on swap memory usage or the "Freeable Memory" in the monitoring data. I can certainly get a bigger instance for this query, but bigger instances are rather expensive. I've run -no sorting, though- queries with bigger tables with this machine specs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with your comment. What I tried to say with my comment was that your sorts would spill to disk, possibly causing the same disk full condition.

Comment: Oh sorry if I misconstrue you comment. In that case, you think the sorts are taking 4 Tb of disk space? I mean, I guess I can increase the memory and add more Tb's, but just wanted to double check if that was a good strategy or I just sucks at SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Following the comments above, I dismantle the CTE into several smaller steps. That not only allowed me to use more indexes, but also to avoid crashing my RDS instance. I hope this helps people in the future in case they are stucked with PostgreSQL 11.